# Netbeans strange behavior

Tags: php, ubuntu, netbeans

Im using ubuntu, netbeans 7.3 for php

[image]

As You can see all 3 methods are involved (+) but just first is marked `{...}`.
Why syntax highlighting is not working, and what is background color highlighting

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be happening. If you can reproduce, please file a bug at https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=php and attach sample code to reproduce it.